# Getting "javax.net.ssl.sslhandshakeexception pkix path building failed sun.security.provider.certpath" error in glue while accessing hive using jdbc

Tags: java, pyspark, hive, aws-glue, aws-glue-connection

i am trying to access hive which is running on on-prmisis  from a glue job

As hive use jdbc connection which requires authentication, i attached certificate(certificate.pem) in the job(using connection) and trying to load the table with below code:

Glue version: 2
spark:2.4

```
jdbcDF = spark.read \
    .format("jdbc") \
    .option("url", "jdbc:hive2://bigdatamr:10000/mydb;ssl=true;transportMode=http;httpPath=gateway/default/hive;trustStorePassword=selfSigned") \
    .option("dbtable", "mydb") \
    .option("user", "myusername") \
    .option("password", "xxxxxxx") \
    .load()
```

but job return below error:

```
javax.net.ssl.sslhandshakeexception pkix path building failed sun.security.provider.certpath
unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

how to resolve this ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["PKIX path building failed" and "unable to find valid certification path to requested target"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21076179/pkix-path-building-failed-and-unable-to-find-valid-certification-path-to-requ)

Comment: I don't think so since the above solution related to jvm and not to spark running on AWS-glue where attaching certificate is parameterized from s3..